# Angular 6 - catch missing image source then try to reset the same source

Tags: angular, html, typescript

I have a list of blobs that a user can add to.
If I have a newly added image hasn't finished uploading by the time the list is refreshed I catch the error as follows, and can see the function kicking off when it should:

```
<img src="https://MyUrl/thumbnails/{{ blob.name }}" width="125" id="MyImg"
        (error)="error()"/>
```

Is it possible to pass that image into the error function to retry setting the source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a directive that binds `src` and retries (sets to null and again to the binded value with a timeout) on `error`. Here is for example something very similar to what you need and a very good starting point: https://medium.com/@sub.metu/angular-fallback-for-broken-images-5cd05c470f08

It basically uses a fallback url in case the src one fails.

Something like this (quickly modified, not tested):

```
import { Directive, OnDestroy, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'img[retrySrc]',
  host: {
    '(error)': 'loadError()',
    '(load)': 'clearTimer()',
  }
})
export class RetrySrcDirective implements OnDestroy {
  private _retrySrc: string;
  private _timer;

  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef<HTMLImageElement>,
  ) {
  }

  @Input()
  set retrySrc(value: string) {
    this.clearTimer();
    this._retrySrc = value;
    this.element.nativeElement.src = value; //each set on src triggers a new request in google Chrome
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.clearTimer();
  }

  loadError() {
    this.clearTimer();
    this._timer = setTimeout(() => this.element.nativeElement.src = this._retrySrc, 5000);
  }

  clearTimer() {
    if (this._timer) {
      clearTimeout(this._timer);
      delete this._timer
    }
  }
}
```

and you use it like:

```
<img [retrySrc]="'https://MyUrl/thumbnails/'+blob.name">
```

Alternatively you can do regular `HttpClient` requests periodically in the directive and set the src once you get a 200 response (use some default src meanwhile).

Comment: at first it wouldn't compile as retrySrc isn't a known property in img, I changes it to src instead but loadError never fires unfortunatelt

Comment: is it to do with a missing host binding?

Comment: Hmm, what does the network tab show for that request?

Comment: @DarkW1nter well, the `host` property from the Component decorator should be the same as `HostBinding`.

Comment: Try this one. It seems to work fine in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-retry-image-load?file=src%2Fapp%2Fretry-src.directive.ts

Comment: works on stackblitz so i'll accept your answer and try to get it into my solution, thanks

Comment: Works well, can I ask you one more thing though?  I can see the original source in the directive, so I can reset it.  Is there any way to set a temp loading image while the retries are happening? Obviously when I try this within the loadError function, as soon as a temp image is loaded successfully it won't try again.  Ideally I want a loading gif while the loadError retries the image load.  Other than that it's great, thanks

Comment: In that case I think you should use HttpClient to poll the image status, while src is set to the loading image. That is so the image doesn't flicker while it retries the to load the image.

Comment: You can use my library: https://github.com/hijamoya/ngx-retryable-image